# Javascript MIDI File player

Tags: javascript, browser, midi

I want to play some midi in the browser. I'm looking this: http://mudcu.be/midi-js/, but I think it's very complicated.

I'd would like something like this:

```
<div id="midi-player"></div>
```

script

```
$('#midi-player').midiplayer({
    src: 'midi/my-midi.mid'
});
```

Anybody knows something similar? Probably with the MIDIJS is possible but I'm very confusing right now. Maybe it's easier than I think but I'd expend more than a day with no results...

Comment: As it stands, this question seems off-topic because you're asking for a 3rd part library. You should post the problems you're having with midi-js (it seems fairly straightforward: `MIDI.Player.loadFile(file, callback); MIDI.Player.start();`)

Comment: That's a great idea for a web component. There's probably already a custom element wrapper for midi.js out there but it would be interesting to make anyway.

Comment: Carpetsmoker yes, but it seems you have to "implement" de midi player actions. (play, pause, stop...)

Answer (score 4):

[MIDI.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js) is your best bet. And i know what i'm talking about since we are using it in a production project. MIDI.js has a LOT of useful features, and it is a wrapper around different browser audio API's, so you don't have to worry about cross browser support. It event allows interacting with MIDI hardware devices!

Loading a file is as simple as:

```
MIDI.Player.loadFile("file.mid", callback);
```

Playing a file is even simpler:

```
MIDI.Player.start()
```

Pausing playback:

```
MIDI.Player.pause();
```

Stopping playback:

```
MIDI.Player.stop();
```

You can control the MIDI instruments used with the Soundfonts. You can load a different Piano or a Guitar with one line of code.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting the idea, thx

Comment: U are welcome. If you need some concrete example or something feel free to ask.

Comment: can we get a link to some repos?

Comment: I've been investigating about this library, and I think that it doesn't allow playing different instruments at the same time. For example I'm trying to play Eye of the tiger and I could not make it work correctly. Maybe the problem is that I need the sound fonts first, or the format is not the propertly. I'll continue investigating